# Android: Problems with EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, kotlin

I have an application written in Kotlin, using the most recent support libraries, which recently have started to get some problems.
I cannot reproduce the issues myself, but I can see multiple occurances of similar crashes reported to Google Play Developer console, under ANRs & Crashes.

The EditText is defined like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/buttonText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewAmountHeader" />
```

I'm not doing anything special with my EditText and it is not custom styled in anyway so I think this might be a bug in the framework.
It seems to occur for all Android versions (4-8)

A sample stacktrace is included below.

Does anyone have a tip how to solve this issue?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange (SpannableStringBuilder.java:1018)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars (SpannableStringBuilder.java:915)
  at android.text.TextUtils.getChars (TextUtils.java:83)
  at android.text.TextUtils.indexOf (TextUtils.java:116)
  at android.text.StaticLayout.generate (StaticLayout.java:200)
  at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow (DynamicLayout.java:284)
  at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init> (DynamicLayout.java:170)
  at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout (TextView.java:7578)
  at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout (TextView.java:7421)
  at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure (TextView.java:7854)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:17495)
  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren (ConstraintLayout.java:934)
  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure (ConstraintLayout.java:973)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:17495)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5363)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:17495)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5363)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure (ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:17495)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5363)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:17495)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5363)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1410)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:17495)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5363)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:310)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure (PhoneWindow.java:2548)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:17495)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2285)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1396)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1595)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:814)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:614)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:584)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:800)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5602)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

Edit: 
It does not help to set the selection as suggested in another thread. This issue is randomly thrown from the framework. I'm not working with selections programatically in my code.

The layout is very clean, it is a ConstraintLayout view and there's just a TextView above the EditText with a header text.

In the code I'm only setting the text in the EditText once upon startup then it is up to the user to modify it.

Comment: Can you please share the entire layout and the code where you using this Edittext. Because the error log doesn't give any hint on isssue with the Edittext alone but the layout itself.

Comment: @YashaswiNP I have updated the description with more information. The screen where this occurs is very simple and does not contain any complex layouts, except for the constraints (included in the XML code above)

Comment: @Mikael I don't think the problem from xml, Could you please share how you set the value to EditText

Comment: Are the crashes limited to any particular manufacturer?

Comment: @Sally I set the value simply by using the setText() method. The text will never contain any spans or formatted data. It shall only be digits.

Comment: @Jahnold No, it seems to occur for multiple devices/vendors. I see crashes from Galaxy* devices, Huawei devices, Motorola devices.

I have also started to see more related crashes in android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt for example. This is weird, it used to work fine but suddenly became problematic with no code changes at all.